# Collision detection with CGPath and CGRect

Tags: ios, collision-detection, cgrect, cgpath

Im making a game which is a shooting game and its 2D and enemies comes from the side. I want the bullets to spread randomly based on an angle and then to draw that bullet I made a `CGPath` and then attach it to a `CAShapeLayer` and then add it to the view.

Now, how can I collision detect this `CGPath/CAShapeLayer` to the enemy's frame?

I know about the `CGPathContainsPoint` but that wont help me here because it is a `CGRect` Im using.

Comment: if you have the path of the bullet, can't you take the last points of the path, and see if those are inside the enemyRect?

Comment: I could follow along with the angle and check every 5px or something and use hitTest

Comment: Yeah. Does the player shoot in every direction? if so then yes. Are there any obstacles in the map? How do you determine the end of a bullet? Or do the go from player to the end of the screen?

Comment: Its only one direction and yes the bullet goes from the player to the edge of the screen.

Comment: In a game that I made, I used box2d, which kind of took care of the collision itself. Start with 5px and see how it treats you.